# xls to csv converter

Tags: python, excel, csv, xls, export-to-csv

I am using win32.client in python for converting my .xlsx and .xls file into a .csv. When I execute this code it's giving an error. My code is:

```
def convertXLS2CSV(aFile):
    '''converts a MS Excel file to csv w/ the same name in the same directory'''

    print "------ beginning to convert XLS to CSV ------"

    try:
        import win32com.client, os
        from win32com.client import constants as c
        excel = win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')

        fileDir, fileName = os.path.split(aFile)
        nameOnly = os.path.splitext(fileName)
        newName = nameOnly[0] + ".csv"
        outCSV = os.path.join(fileDir, newName)
        workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(aFile)
        workbook.SaveAs(outCSV, c.xlCSVMSDOS) # 24 represents xlCSVMSDOS
        workbook.Close(False)
        excel.Quit()
        del excel

        print "...Converted " + nameOnly + " to CSV"
    except:
        print ">>>>>>> FAILED to convert " + aFile + " to CSV!"

convertXLS2CSV("G:\\hello.xlsx")
```

I am not able to find the error in this code. Please help.

Comment: Please post the error and full taceback

Comment: remove the try/except first, you aren't going to get a helpful error like that.

Answer (score 79):

I would use xlrd - it's faster, cross platform and works directly with the file.

[As of version 0.8.0](https://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changes.html#aug-2012), `xlrd` reads both XLS and XLSX files.

But [as of version 2.0.0](https://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changes.html#id1), support was reduced back to **only** XLS.

```
import xlrd
import csv

def csv_from_excel():
    wb = xlrd.open_workbook('your_workbook.xls')
    sh = wb.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
    your_csv_file = open('your_csv_file.csv', 'wb')
    wr = csv.writer(your_csv_file, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

    for rownum in xrange(sh.nrows):
        wr.writerow(sh.row_values(rownum))

    your_csv_file.close()
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `wr.writerow(sh.row_values(rownum))`? See [here](https://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlrd/trunk/xlrd/doc/xlrd.html#sheet.Sheet.row_values-method).

Comment: Does it support datetime conversion from xls datmode to normal datetime

Comment: I believe it's best practice to wrap the for loop in a try..finally, with your_csv_file.close() called within the finally block. Something to do with closing the file regardless of whether an error is thrown during access?

Comment: If you don't know the name of the sheet (i.e. it's not `Sheet1`) then you can use `wb.sheet_by_index(0)` to get the first sheet, regardless of its name.

Comment: CAUTION: this approach will not preserve Excel formatting of certain numbers. Integer-formatted numeric values will be written in decimal form (e.g. 2 -> 2.0), integer-formatted formulas will also be written in decimal form (e.g. =A1/B2 shows as 1 but exports as 0.9912319), and leading zeroes of text-formatted numeric values will be stripped (e.g. "007" -> "7.0"). Good luck querying for Mr. Bond in your database of secret agents! If you are lucky, these issues will crop up in obvious failures. If you are not lucky, they could silently poison your data.

Comment: any suggestions on what to do instead, @Stew?

Comment: for python 3: use `your_csv_file = open(xls_path, 'w')` (not 'wb'). the csv module takes input in text mode, not bytes mode. Otherwise, you'll get:  `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`

Answer (score 63):

I would use `pandas`. The computationally heavy parts are written in cython or c-extensions to speed up the process and the syntax is very clean. For example, if you want to turn "Sheet1" from the file "your_workbook.xls" into the file "your_csv.csv", you just use the top-level function `read_excel` and the method `to_csv` from the `DataFrame` class as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
data_xls = pd.read_excel('your_workbook.xls', 'Sheet1', index_col=None)
data_xls.to_csv('your_csv.csv', encoding='utf-8')
```

Setting `encoding='utf-8'` alleviates the `UnicodeEncodeError` mentioned in other answers.

Comment: it does not work in case if you have some other languages text in rows.it shows ??? in text

Comment: @philE This is too slow. Use xlsx2csv

Comment: any tips on handling newline characters that might be in excel cell contents ?

Answer (score 43):

Maybe someone find this ready-to-use piece of code useful. It allows to create CSVs from all spreadsheets in Excel's workbook.

[image]

**Python 2:**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import xlrd
import csv
from os import sys
 
def csv_from_excel(excel_file):
    workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(excel_file)
    all_worksheets = workbook.sheet_names()
    for worksheet_name in all_worksheets:
        worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name(worksheet_name)
        with open(u'{}.csv'.format(worksheet_name), 'wb') as your_csv_file:
            wr = csv.writer(your_csv_file, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
            for rownum in xrange(worksheet.nrows):
                wr.writerow([unicode(entry).encode("utf-8") for entry in worksheet.row_values(rownum)])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    csv_from_excel(sys.argv[1])
```

**Python 3:**

```
import xlrd
import csv
from os import sys

def csv_from_excel(excel_file):
    workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(excel_file)
    all_worksheets = workbook.sheet_names()
    for worksheet_name in all_worksheets:
        worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name(worksheet_name)
        with open(u'{}.csv'.format(worksheet_name), 'w', encoding="utf-8") as your_csv_file:
            wr = csv.writer(your_csv_file, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
            for rownum in range(worksheet.nrows):
                wr.writerow(worksheet.row_values(rownum))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    csv_from_excel(sys.argv[1])
```

Comment: just a couple of annotations: some worksheets may be empty. I don't see no utility on generating empty CSV files, better do a previous evaluation on worksheet.nrows > 0 before doing anythin.

Comment: also, it would be better to use contexts for the CSV file ;)

Comment: You can skip empty sheets with `if worksheet.nrows == 0: continue`

Comment: I'm getting 
 `File "<ipython-input-24-5fa644cde9f8>", line 15, in <module>
    csv_from_excel("Analyse Article Lustucru PF.xlsx")

  File "<ipython-input-24-5fa644cde9f8>", line 6, in csv_from_excel
    with open('{}.csv'.format(worksheet_name), 'wb') as your_csv_file:

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)` do you know how to deal with it ?

Comment: @OrhanYazar try with `u'{}.csv'.format(worksheet_name)` notice `u` in the beginning standing for unciode

Answer (score 22):

I'd use [csvkit](https://github.com/onyxfish/csvkit), which uses xlrd (for xls) and openpyxl (for xlsx) to convert just about any tabular data to csv.

Once installed, with its dependencies, it's a matter of:

```
python in2csv myfile > myoutput.csv
```

It takes care of all the format detection issues, so you can pass it just about any tabular data source. It's cross-platform too (no win32 dependency).

Comment: Like this tool also. Not quite relevant to this question, but I've met a mention of this csvkit thing in [this book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920032823.do) alongside with some other data processing utils that allow you to transform data right inside of your shell.

Answer (score 8):

First read your excel spreadsheet into pandas, below code will import your excel spreadsheet into pandas as a OrderedDict type which contain all of your worksheet as dataframes. Then simply use worksheet_name as a key to access specific worksheet as a dataframe and save only required worksheet as csv file by using df.to_csv(). Hope this will workout in your case.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('YourExcel.xlsx', sheet_name=None)
df['worksheet_name'].to_csv('YourCsv.csv')
```

If your Excel file contain only one worksheet then simply use below code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('YourExcel.xlsx')
df.to_csv('YourCsv.csv')
```

If someone want to convert all the excel worksheets from single excel workbook to the different csv files, try below code:

```
import pandas as pd
def excelTOcsv(filename):
    df = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name=None)  
    for key, value in df.items(): 
        return df[key].to_csv('%s.csv' %key)
```

This function is working as a multiple Excel sheet of same excel workbook to multiple csv file converter. Where key is the sheet name and value is the content inside sheet.

Answer (score 3):

[xlsx2csv](https://github.com/dilshod/xlsx2csv) is **faster** than pandas and xlrd.

```
xlsx2csv -s 0 crunchbase_monthly_.xlsx cruchbase
```

excel file usually comes with n sheetname.

```
-s is sheetname index.
```

then, cruchbase folder will be created, each sheet belongs to xlsx will be converted to a single csv.

p.s. [csvkit](https://github.com/wireservice/csvkit) is awesome too.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting an [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1147766/116475) from [Scott Ming](https://superuser.com/users/644678/scott-ming), which works with workbook containing multiple sheets:

Here is a python script [getsheets.py](https://gist.github.com/scottming/99c09685360376d4cac2de7c891e8050/9670acd5044d11871188e04b8123263ad132f512) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20180125032406/https://gist.github.com/scottming/99c09685360376d4cac2de7c891e8050/9670acd5044d11871188e04b8123263ad132f512)), you should install `pandas` and `xlrd` before you use it.

Run this:

```
pip3 install pandas xlrd  # or `pip install pandas xlrd`
```

How does it works?

```
$ python3 getsheets.py -h
Usage: getsheets.py [OPTIONS] INPUTFILE

Convert a Excel file with multiple sheets to several file with one sheet.

Examples:

    getsheets filename

    getsheets filename -f csv

Options:
-f, --format [xlsx|csv]  Default xlsx.
-h, --help               Show this message and exit.
```

Convert to several xlsx:

```
$ python3 getsheets.py goods_temp.xlsx
Sheet.xlsx Done!
Sheet1.xlsx Done!

All Done!
```

Convert to several csv:

```
$ python3 getsheets.py goods_temp.xlsx -f csv
Sheet.csv Done!
Sheet1.csv Done!

All Done!
```

`getsheets.py`:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import click
import os
import pandas as pd


def file_split(file):
    s = file.split('.')
    name = '.'.join(s[:-1])  # get directory name
    return name


def getsheets(inputfile, fileformat):
    name = file_split(inputfile)
    try:
        os.makedirs(name)
    except:
        pass

    df1 = pd.ExcelFile(inputfile)
    for x in df1.sheet_names:
        print(x + '.' + fileformat, 'Done!')
        df2 = pd.read_excel(inputfile, sheetname=x)
        filename = os.path.join(name, x + '.' + fileformat)
        if fileformat == 'csv':
            df2.to_csv(filename, index=False)
        else:
            df2.to_excel(filename, index=False)
    print('\nAll Done!')


CONTEXT_SETTINGS = dict(help_option_names=['-h', '--help'])


@click.command(context_settings=CONTEXT_SETTINGS)
@click.argument('inputfile')
@click.option('-f', '--format', type=click.Choice([
    'xlsx', 'csv']), default='xlsx', help='Default xlsx.')
def cli(inputfile, format):
    '''Convert a Excel file with multiple sheets to several file with one sheet.

    Examples:

    \b
        getsheets filename

    \b
        getsheets filename -f csv
    '''
    if format == 'csv':
        getsheets(inputfile, 'csv')
    else:
        getsheets(inputfile, 'xlsx')


cli()
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use Pandas lib of Python to conevert xls file to csv file
Below code will convert xls file to csv file .
import pandas as pd

Read Excel File from Local Path :

```
df = pd.read_excel("C:/Users/IBM_ADMIN/BU GPA Scorecard.xlsx",sheetname=1)
```

Trim Spaces present on columns :

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()
```

Send Data frame to CSV file which will be pipe symbol delimted and without Index :

```
df.to_csv("C:/Users/IBM_ADMIN/BU GPA Scorecard csv.csv",sep="|",index=False)
```

Comment: with your code, i am getting an error:  ```>>> dfs = pd.read_excel(file_name, sheet_name=None)
>>> dfs.columns = dfs.columns.str.strip()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'collections.OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'columns'```

Answer (score 1):

Python is not the best tool for this task. I tried several approaches in Python but none of them work 100% (e.g. 10% converts to 0.1, or column types are messed up, etc). The right tool here is PowerShell, because it is an MS product (as is Excel) and has the best integration.

Simply download [this](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/How-to-convert-Excel-xlsx-d9521619) PowerShell script, edit line 47 to enter the path for the folder containing the Excel files and run the script using PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

Using xlrd is a flawed way to do this, because you lose the Date Formats in Excel.

My use case is the following.

Take an Excel File with more than one sheet and convert each one into a file of its own.

I have done this using the xlsx2csv library and calling this using a subprocess.

```
import csv
import sys, os, json, re, time
import subprocess

def csv_from_excel(fname):
    subprocess.Popen(["xlsx2csv " + fname + " --all -d '|' -i -p "
                      "'<New Sheet>' > " + 'test.csv'], shell=True)

    return

lstSheets = csv_from_excel(sys.argv[1])

time.sleep(3) # system needs to wait a second to recognize the file was  written

with open('[YOUR PATH]/test.csv') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    firstSheet = True

    for line in lines:
        if line.startswith('<New Sheet>'):
            if firstSheet:
                sh_2_fname = line.replace('<New Sheet>', '').strip().replace(' - ', '_').replace(' ','_')
                print(sh_2_fname)
                sh2f = open(sh_2_fname+".csv", "w")
                firstSheet = False
            else:
                sh2f.close()
                sh_2_fname = line.replace('<New Sheet>', '').strip().replace(' - ', '_').replace(' ','_')
                print(sh_2_fname)
                sh2f = open(sh_2_fname+".csv", "w")
        else:
            sh2f.write(line)
sh2f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tested all anwers, but they were all too slow for me. If you have Excel installed you can use the COM.

I thought initially it would be slower since it will load everything for the actual Excel application, but it isn't for huge files. Maybe because the algorithm for opening and saving files runs a heavily optimized compiled code, Microsoft guys make a lot of money for it after all.

```
import sys
import os
import glob
from win32com.client import Dispatch

def main(path):
    excel = Dispatch("Excel.Application")
    if is_full_path(path):
        process_file(excel, path)
    else:
        files = glob.glob(path)
        for file_path in files:
            process_file(excel, file_path)
    excel.Quit()

def process_file(excel, path):
    fullpath = os.path.abspath(path)
    full_csv_path = os.path.splitext(fullpath)[0] + '.csv'
    workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(fullpath)
    workbook.Worksheets(1).SaveAs(full_csv_path, 6)
    workbook.Saved = 1
    workbook.Close()


def is_full_path(path):
    return path.find(":") > -1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1])
```

This is very raw code and won't check for errors, print help or anything, it will just create a csv file for each file that matches the pattern you entered in the function so you can batch process a lot of files only launching excel application once.

Answer (score 0):

As much as I hate to rely on Windows Excel proprietary software, which is not cross-platform, my testing of `csvkit` for .xls, which uses `xlrd` under the hood, failed to correctly parse dates (even when using the commandline parameters to specify strptime format).

For example, [this xls file](http://www.cboe.com/publish/TTDailyNewSeries/late1231.xls), when parsed with `csvkit`, will convert cell `G1` of `12/31/2002` to `37621`, whereas when converted to csv via excel -> save_as (using below) cell `G1` will be `"December 31, 2002"`.

```
import re
import os
from win32com.client import Dispatch
xlCSVMSDOS = 24

class CsvConverter(object):
    def __init__(self, *, input_dir, output_dir):
        self._excel = None
        self.input_dir = input_dir
        self.output_dir = output_dir

        if not os.path.isdir(self.output_dir):
            os.makedirs(self.output_dir)

    def isSheetEmpty(self, sheet):
        # https://archive.is/RuxR7
        # WorksheetFunction.CountA(ActiveSheet.UsedRange) = 0 And ActiveSheet.Shapes.Count = 0

        return \
            (not self._excel.WorksheetFunction.CountA(sheet.UsedRange)) \
            and \
            (not sheet.Shapes.Count)

    def getNonEmptySheets(self, wb, as_name=False):
        return [ \
            (sheet.Name if as_name else sheet) \
            for sheet in wb.Sheets \
            if not self.isSheetEmpty(sheet) \
        ]

    def saveWorkbookAsCsv(self, wb, csv_path):
        non_empty_sheet_names = self.getNonEmptySheets(wb, as_name=True)

        assert (len(non_empty_sheet_names) == 1), \
            "Expected exactly 1 sheet but found %i non-empty sheets: '%s'" \
            %(
                len(non_empty_sheet_names),
                "', '".join(name.replace("'", r"\'") for name in non_empty_sheet_names)
            )

        wb.Worksheets(non_empty_sheet_names[0]).SaveAs(csv_path, xlCSVMSDOS)
        wb.Saved = 1

    def isXlsFilename(self, filename):
        return bool(re.search(r'(?i)\.xls$', filename))

    def batchConvertXlsToCsv(self):
        xls_names = tuple( filename for filename in next(os.walk(self.input_dir))[2] if self.isXlsFilename(filename) )

        self._excel = Dispatch('Excel.Application')
        try:
            for xls_name in xls_names:
                csv_path = os.path.join(self.output_dir, '%s.csv' %os.path.splitext(xls_name)[0])
                if not os.path.isfile(csv_path):
                    workbook = self._excel.Workbooks.Open(os.path.join(self.input_dir, xls_name))
                    try:
                        self.saveWorkbookAsCsv(workbook, csv_path)
                    finally:
                        workbook.Close()
        finally:
            if not len(self._excel.Workbooks):
                self._excel.Quit()

            self._excel = None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    self = CsvConverter(
        input_dir='C:\\data\\xls\\',
        output_dir='C:\\data\\csv\\'
    )

    self.batchConvertXlsToCsv()
```

The above will take an `input_dir` containing .xls and output them to `output_dir` as .csv -- it will `assert` that there is exactly 1 non-empty sheet in the .xls; if you need to handle multiple sheets into multiple csv then you'll need to edit `saveWorkbookAsCsv`.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to use `xlrd` library in order to convert the format `xlsx` into `csv`, but I was getting error: `xlrd.biffh.XLRDError: Excel xlsx file; not supported`. That was happening because this package is no longer reading any other format unless `xls`, according to [xlrd documentation](https://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Following the answer from [Chris Withers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65266270) I was able to change the engine for the function `read_excel()` from `pandas`, then I was able to a create a function that is converting any sheet from your Excel spreadsheet you want to successfully.
In order to work the function below, don't forget to install the `openpyxl` library from [here](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

Function:

```
import os
import pathlib
import pandas as pd

# Function to convert excel spreadsheet into csv format
def Excel_to_csv():
    # Excel file full path
    excel_file = os.path.join(os.path.sep, pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.resolve(), "Excel_Spreadsheet.xlsx")    
    # Excel sheets
    excel_sheets = ['Sheet1', 'Sheet2', 'Sheet3']

    for sheet in excel_sheets:
        # Create dataframe for each sheet
        df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_excel(excel_file, sheet, index_col=None, engine='openpyxl'))
        # Export to csv. i.e: sheet_name.csv
        df.to_csv(os.path.join(os.path.sep, pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.resolve(), sheet + '.csv'), sep=",", encoding='utf-8', index=False, header=True)

# Runs the excel_to_csv function:
Excel_to_csv()
```