# python xlrd: how to remove quotation marks when converting excel file to csv

Tags: python, xlrd

I used this method [xls to csv converter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884353/xls-to-csv-convertor) to convert excel files(xls and xlsx) to csv files. But when converting to csv files, it adds `" "` to each cell.

Now, my question is how to remove the quotation marks when converting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the CSV writer's `quoting` argument to whichever of the csv module's quoting constants has the behavior you want.

http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.QUOTE_ALL