# python cvs and xlrd: how to write csv file cell by cell

Tags: python, csv, xlrd

I used this method [xls to csv converter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884353/xls-to-csv-convertor) to convert excel files(xls and xlsx) to csv files.

But in this example, it uses `csv.write.writerow()` method, and I cannot find any method related to write cell by cell from [csv writer object](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#writer-objects).

So how can I write to csv cell by cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any built-in support for writing cell by cell (or column by column).  Why do you want to do this anyway?  If you are trying to convert an Excel file to CSV, it is simple enough to do it row by row.  If for whatever reason you really just want to write a few *specific* cells, in a nonsequential manner, you have to manage those writes yourself, perhaps in a 2-dimensional array (a list of lists would work fine) and then write *that* data structure out row by row to the CSV.

Comment: I just realized how stupid I am after I posted this question. Because I need to handle some specific cells, I cannot write row by row. So I need to write to a file by myself rather than using csv library.