# writing excel to csv using xlrd library adding float value insted of integers

Tags: python, excel, csv

I'm coming from the [xls to csv converter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884353/xls-to-csv-convertor) . It helps me to converting excel sheets to csv files.

I've integer values in my excel-sheets, while I'm writing them into csv files, they got converted into float values. example.

```
1 > 1.0
```

My data is something like,

```
no  name   marks  friend
01  kirk    190   sandy
02  stark   100   kim
```

all the above integer becomes float.

```
no    name    marks   friend
01.0  kirk    190.0    sandy
02.0  stark   100.0    kim
```

Is there any solution to override the issue?

code for reference,

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import xlrd
import csv
from os import sys

def csv_from_excel(excel_file):
    workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(excel_file)
    all_worksheets = workbook.sheet_names()
    for worksheet_name in all_worksheets:
        worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name(worksheet_name)
        your_csv_file = open(''.join([worksheet_name,'.csv']), 'wb')
        wr = csv.writer(your_csv_file, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

        for rownum in xrange(worksheet.nrows):
            wr.writerow([unicode(entry).encode("utf-8") for entry in worksheet.row_values(rownum)])
        your_csv_file.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    csv_from_excel(sys.argv[1])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be more careful in this part:

```
[unicode(entry).encode("utf-8") for entry in worksheet.row_values(rownum)]
```

You transform `entry` to a string (unicode object) right away, and then encode this string to utf-8 representation. Instead, you should inspect `entry` and deal with it on a case-to-case basis.

The documentation is a little thin: http://www.lexicon.net/sjmachin/xlrd.html#xlrd.Sheet.row_values-method -- I guess `entry` is of type `Cell` (http://www.lexicon.net/sjmachin/xlrd.html#xlrd.Cell-class), but I guess you need to experiment.