# How to open file and save as csv

Tags: python, csv

I currently export reports from a website as a 'csv' file. But, when I open them I get this pop up message:

> The file you are trying to open, 'Jul2015.csv', is in a different
>   format than specified by the file extension. Verify that the file is
>   not corrupted and is from a trusted source before opening the file. Do
>   you want to open the file now?

I click 'yes' and the file opens in some sort of 'xls' format. So I save as a 'csv' format and when I report the newly saved file it follows the 'csv' format.

So my question is, how can I in python open the initial exported report and save as a 'csv' so I can avoid the inconsistent formatting?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [xls to csv convertor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884353/xls-to-csv-convertor)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
import pandas as pd
data_xls = pd.read_excel('export.csv', 'Sheet1', index_col=None)
data_xls.to_csv('exceltocsv.csv', encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: FYI, this doesn't work if the file won't read in via read_excel because it's a XML spreadsheet masquerading as a .xls file.

Answer (score 0):

this should work too, and doesn't use an external library.

```
with open("exported.csv", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
with open("xlstocsv.csv", "r") as g:
    g.writelines(lines)
```