# Reading large number of Excel files into Apache Spark

Tags: java, python-3.x, hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark

I have 100 Excel (*.xlsx) files stored in HDFS.
The 100 *.xlsx files are organized into 10 directories, as shown below:

```
/user/cloudera/raw_data/dataPoint1/dataPoint.xlsx
/user/cloudera/raw_data/dataPoint2/dataPoint.xlsx
...
..
.
/user/cloudera/raw_data/dataPoint10/dataPoint.xlsx
```

Reading in one of *.xlsx files from above using

```
rawData = sc.textFile("/user/cloudera/raw_data/dataPoint1/dataPoint.xlsx")
```

threw gibberish data!

One obvious suggestion I received was to use the [Gnumeric](http://www.gnumeric.org) spreadsheet application's command-line utility called [ssconvert](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnumeric/stable/sect-files-ssconvert.html):

```
$ ssconvert dataPoint.xlsx dataPoint.csv
```

and then dump it into the HDFS, so I can read the *.csv file directly. **But that is not what I am trying to solve or is the requirement.**

Solutions in `Python` (preferable) and `Java` would be appreciated. I am a rookie, so a detailed walkthrough would be really helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would load each file with xlrd https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd process it and then union all the data.

Comment: @TomRon when you say process it, do you mean extract the sheet data to a python list and then load the list to an RDD?

Comment: Try to use pandas as described (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884353/xls-to-csv-convertor) to convert to csv and then load into Spark RDD

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code to read excel files in Spark directly from HDFS using Hadoop FileSystem API. However you have to implement Apache POI API to parse the data

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import java.util.Date
import scala.io.Source
import java.io.{ InputStream, FileInputStream, File }
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.{ Cell, Row, Workbook, Sheet }
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel._
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import java.net._

object Excel {
  def main(arr: Array[String]) {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Excel-read-write").setMaster("local[2]")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val fs = FileSystem.get(URI.create("hdfs://localhost:9000/user/files/timetable.xlsx"),new Configuration());
    val path=  new Path("hdfs://localhost:9000/user/files/timetable.xlsx");
    val InputStream = fs.open(path)
    read(InputStream)
  }
  def read(in:InputStream)={

  }
}
```

read(in:InputStream) method is where you implement Apache POI API to parse the data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Spark Excel Library](https://github.com/crealytics/spark-excel) for converting xlsx files to DataFrames directly. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42748705/5709148) with a detailed example.

As of version 0.8.4, the library does not support streaming and loads all the source rows into memory for conversion.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to build yourself a custom XLSX to CSV Converter, The Apache POI Event API would be Ideal for this. This API is suitable for Spreadsheets with large memory footprints. Look out what is it about  [here](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html).
Here is an example [XSLX processing with the XSSF Event code](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xssf/eventusermodel/examples/FromHowTo.java)

Comment: Can you please elaborate with an example or throw some more light?

Comment: If you've gone through the second link I provided, You will see a class SheetHandler which implements two methods named startElement and endElement. These methods receive notifications of different sheets elements like a cell value, end of a row etc. You will notice, the cell values are being printed to standard output in the method in method endElement. Similarly you can have an output path and write these values to a CSV file or can customize these method as well to do whatever on occurrence of an attribute or its value.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the HadoopOffice library:
https://github.com/ZuInnoTe/hadoopoffice/wiki

Works with Spark and if you can use the Spark2 data source API you can use also Python. If you cannot use the Spark2 data source API then you can use the standard Spark APIs for reading/writing files using a HadoopFile Format provided by the HadoopOffice library.