# How to read multiple Excel files and concatenate them into one Apache Spark DataFrame?

Tags: excel, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset, spark-excel

Recently I wanted to do Spark Machine Learning Lab from Spark Summit 2016.  Training video is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fROnFlD3Isw) and exported  notebook is available [here.](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1BTTPu5-xDOZTFDV1pELVlhdDg)

The dataset used in the lab can be downloaded from [UCI Machine Learning Repository](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Combined+Cycle+Power+Plant). It contains a set of readings from various sensors in a gas-fired power generation plant. The format is xlsx file with five sheets.

To use the data in the lab I needed to read all the sheets form the Excel file and to concatenate them into one Spark DataFrame. During the training they are using Databricks Notebook but I was using IntelliJ IDEA with Scala and evaluating the code in the console.

The first step was to save all the  Excel sheets into separate xlsx files named `sheet1.xlxs`, `sheet2.xlsx` etc. and put them into `sheets` directory.

How to read all the Excel files and concatenate them into one Apache Spark DataFrame?

Answer (score 5):

For this I have used [spark-excel](https://index.scala-lang.org/crealytics/spark-excel) package. It can be added to build.sbt file as : `libraryDependencies += "com.crealytics" %% "spark-excel" % "0.8.2"`

The code to execute in IntelliJ IDEA Scala Console was:

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.sql.{SparkSession, DataFrame}
import java.io.File

val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Excel to DataFrame").setMaster("local[*]")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
sc.setLogLevel("WARN")

val spark = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()

// Function to read xlsx file using spark-excel. 
// This code format with "trailing dots" can be sent to IJ Scala Console as a block.
def readExcel(file: String): DataFrame = spark.read.
  format("com.crealytics.spark.excel").
  option("location", file).
  option("useHeader", "true").
  option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "true").
  option("inferSchema", "true").
  option("addColorColumns", "False").
  load()

val dir = new File("./data/CCPP/sheets")
val excelFiles = dir.listFiles.sorted.map(f => f.toString)  // Array[String]

val dfs = excelFiles.map(f => readExcel(f))  // Array[DataFrame]
val ppdf = dfs.reduce(_.union(_))  // DataFrame 

ppdf.count()  // res3: Long = 47840
ppdf.show(5)
```

Console output:

```
+-----+-----+-------+-----+------+
|   AT|    V|     AP|   RH|    PE|
+-----+-----+-------+-----+------+
|14.96|41.76|1024.07|73.17|463.26|
|25.18|62.96|1020.04|59.08|444.37|
| 5.11| 39.4|1012.16|92.14|488.56|
|20.86|57.32|1010.24|76.64|446.48|
|10.82| 37.5|1009.23|96.62| 473.9|
+-----+-----+-------+-----+------+
only showing top 5 rows
```

Comment: Not dure if it processes all tabs of an excel of not. Does it?

Comment: I will try it, but it would save time knowing this up front

Answer (score 0):

We need spark-excel library for this, can be obtained from

https://github.com/crealytics/spark-excel#scala-api

1. clone the git project from above github link and build using "sbt package"
2. Using Spark 2 to run the spark-shell

> spark-shell --driver-class-path ./spark-excel_2.11-0.8.3.jar
>   --master=yarn-client

3. Import the necessary

> import org.apache.spark.sql._
>   import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
>   `val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)`

4. Set excel doc path

> `val document = "path to excel doc"`

5. Execute the below function for creating dataframe out of it

> ```
> val dataDF = sqlContext.read
>                           .format("com.crealytics.spark.excel")
>                           .option("sheetName", "Sheet Name")
>                           .option("useHeader", "true")
>                           .option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "false")
>                           .option("inferSchema", "false")
>                           .option("location", document)
>                           .option("addColorColumns", "false")
>                           .load(document)
> ```

That's all! now you can perform the Dataframe operation on the **dataDF** object.

Comment: Actually, I've to store a spark dataframe in a excel file format with few column as a read only nature? Can you guide me regarding the same?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this Spark Scala code might help.

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{Path, FileSystem}
import org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil
import org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InMemoryFileIndex
import java.net.URI

def listFiles(basep: String, globp: String): Seq[String] = {
  val conf = new Configuration(sc.hadoopConfiguration)
  val fs = FileSystem.get(new URI(basep), conf)

  def validated(path: String): Path = {
    if(path startsWith "/") new Path(path)
    else new Path("/" + path)
  }

  val fileCatalog = InMemoryFileIndex.bulkListLeafFiles(
    paths = SparkHadoopUtil.get.globPath(fs, Path.mergePaths(validated(basep), validated(globp))),
    hadoopConf = conf,
    filter = null,
    sparkSession = spark)

  fileCatalog.flatMap(_._2.map(_.path))
}

val root = "/mnt/{path to your file directory}"
val globp = "[^_]*"

val files = listFiles(root, globp)
val paths=files.toVector
```

Loop the vector to read multiple files:

```
for (path <- paths) {
     print(path.toString)

     val df= spark.read.
                   format("com.crealytics.spark.excel").
                   option("useHeader", "true").
                   option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "false").
                   option("inferSchema", "false"). 
                   option("addColorColumns", "false").
                   load(path.toString)
}
```