# How to construct Dataframe from a Excel (xls,xlsx) file in Scala Spark?

Tags: excel, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-excel

I have a large `Excel(xlsx and xls)` file with multiple sheet and I need convert it to `RDD` or `Dataframe` so that it can be joined to other `dataframe` later. I was thinking of using [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/) and save it as a `CSV` and then read `csv` in `dataframe`. But if there is any libraries or API that can help in this Process would be easy. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Check this answer for newbies with steps
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47721326/2112382

Comment: Actually, I've to store a spark dataframe in a excel file format with few column as a read only nature? Can you guide me regarding the same?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The solution to your problem is to use `Spark Excel` dependency in your project.

[Spark Excel](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.crealytics/spark-excel_2.11/0.8.3) has flexible `options` to play with.

I have tested the following code to read from `excel` and convert it to `dataframe` and it just works perfect

```
def readExcel(file: String): DataFrame = sqlContext.read
    .format("com.crealytics.spark.excel")
    .option("location", file)
    .option("useHeader", "true")
    .option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "true")
    .option("inferSchema", "true")
    .option("addColorColumns", "False")
    .load()

val data = readExcel("path to your excel file")

data.show(false)
```

you can give `sheetname` as `option` if your excel sheet has multiple sheets

```
.option("sheetName", "Sheet2")
```

I hope its helpful

Comment: So it processes all tabs if sheetName not specified?

Comment: I used `spark.read.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel").option("location","/home/mylocation/myfile.xlsx").load()` but got `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter "path" is missing in options.`

Comment: @Regressor try not using location and using path in load as mentioned in https://github.com/crealytics/spark-excel

Comment: `'sheetName'` doesn't work anymore. You have to use `'dataAddress'` - https://github.com/crealytics/spark-excel/issues/118

Answer (score 14):

Here are *read* and *write* examples to read from and write into excel **with full set of options.**..

Source [spark-excel from crealytics](https://github.com/crealytics/spark-excel)

*Scala API
Spark 2.0+:*

***Create a DataFrame from an Excel file***

```
    import org.apache.spark.sql._

val spark: SparkSession = ???
val df = spark.read
         .format("com.crealytics.spark.excel")
        .option("sheetName", "Daily") // Required
        .option("useHeader", "true") // Required
        .option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "false") // Optional, default: true
        .option("inferSchema", "false") // Optional, default: false
        .option("addColorColumns", "true") // Optional, default: false
        .option("startColumn", 0) // Optional, default: 0
        .option("endColumn", 99) // Optional, default: Int.MaxValue
        .option("timestampFormat", "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss") // Optional, default: yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fffffffff]
        .option("maxRowsInMemory", 20) // Optional, default None. If set, uses a streaming reader which can help with big files
        .option("excerptSize", 10) // Optional, default: 10. If set and if schema inferred, number of rows to infer schema from
        .schema(myCustomSchema) // Optional, default: Either inferred schema, or all columns are Strings
        .load("Worktime.xlsx")
```

**Write a DataFrame to an Excel file**

```
    df.write
      .format("com.crealytics.spark.excel")
      .option("sheetName", "Daily")
      .option("useHeader", "true")
      .option("dateFormat", "yy-mmm-d") // Optional, default: yy-m-d h:mm
      .option("timestampFormat", "mm-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss") // Optional, default: yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.000
      .mode("overwrite")
      .save("Worktime2.xlsx")
```

> Note: Instead of sheet1 or  sheet2 you can use their names as well..
>   in this example given above ***Daily*** is sheet name.

- If you want to use it from spark shell...

This package can be added to Spark using the `--packages` command line option. For example, to include it when starting the spark shell:

```
    $SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-shell --packages com.crealytics:spark-excel_2.11:0.13.1
```

- Dependencies needs to be added (in case of maven etc...):

> ```
> groupId: com.crealytics
> artifactId: spark-excel_2.11
> version: 0.13.1
> ```

---

***[Further reading : See my article (How to do Simple reporting with Excel sheets using Apache Spark, Scala ?) of how to write in to excel file after an aggregations in to many excel sheets](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-do-simple-reporting-excel-sheets-using-apache-spark-ghadiyaram/)***

> ***Tip :*** This is very useful approach  particularly for writing 
>   maven test cases where you can place excel sheets with sample data in excel 
>   `src/main/resources` folder and you can access them in your unit test cases(scala/java), which creates `DataFrame`[s] out of excel sheet...

- Another option you could consider is 
  [spark-hadoopoffice-ds](https://github.com/ZuInnoTe/spark-hadoopoffice-ds/)

> A Spark datasource for the HadoopOffice library. This Spark datasource
>   assumes at least Spark 2.0.1. However, the HadoopOffice library can
>   also be used directly from Spark 1.x. Currently this datasource
>   supports the following formats of the HadoopOffice library:
>
> Excel Datasource format: `org.zuinnote.spark.office.Excel` Loading and
>   Saving of old Excel (.xls) and new Excel (.xlsx) This datasource is
>   available on [Spark-packages.org](https://spark-packages.org/package/ZuInnoTe/spark-hadoopoffice-ds) and on [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Chadoopoffice).

Comment: I used `spark.read.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel").option("location","/home/mylocation/myfile.xlsx").load()` but got `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter "path" is missing in options.`

Comment: Actually, I've to store a spark dataframe in a excel file format with few column as a read only nature? Can you guide me regarding the same?

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you can use the HadoopOffice library (https://github.com/ZuInnoTe/hadoopoffice/wiki), which supports also encrypted Excel documents and linked workbooks, amongst other features. Of course Spark is also supported.

Comment: Hello All,Can we use the above to write data to multiple tabs in an excel sheet?.

Comment: I assume you mean multiple sheets in an Excel workbook. Yes, it can write to multiple sheets. Basically you define a SpreadSheetCellDAO which specifies formattedValue, Comment, Formula, Address and Sheet. However, to support you more I would need to know more about your use case. Feel free to provide the information as Github issue: https://github.com/ZuInnoTe/hadoopoffice/issues

Comment: I have a column that has the values with double quotes eg: "xxxxx,yyy,zzz". Because of this, the value is not considered as a single column, if I see the dataframe, instead of one column, it is showing as 3 columns

Comment: That is strange. There is no logic to split that column based on commas or double quotes. Can you please check with the Apache POI people: https://poi.apache.org/help/index.html ? Can you also please verify that it is indeed just one column and provide an example file?

Answer (score 1):

I have used com.crealytics.spark.excel-0.11 version jar and created in spark-Java, it would be the same in scala too, just need to change javaSparkContext to SparkContext.

```
tempTable = new SQLContext(javaSparkContxt).read()
    .format("com.crealytics.spark.excel") 
    .option("sheetName", "sheet1")
    .option("useHeader", "false") // Required 
    .option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls","false") // Optional, default: true 
    .option("inferSchema", "false") //Optional, default: false 
    .option("addColorColumns", "false") //Required
    .option("timestampFormat", "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss") // Optional, default: yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fffffffff] .schema(schema)
    .schema(schema)
    .load("hdfs://localhost:8020/user/tester/my.xlsx");
```

Comment: Actually, I've to store a spark dataframe in a excel file format with few column as a read only nature? Can you guide me regarding the same?

Answer (score 1):

Hope this should help.

```
val df_excel= spark.read.
                   format("com.crealytics.spark.excel").
                   option("useHeader", "true").
                   option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "false").
                   option("inferSchema", "false"). 
                   option("addColorColumns", "false").load(file_path)

display(df_excel)
```

Comment: Actually, I've to store a spark dataframe in a excel file format with few column as a read only nature? Can you guide me regarding the same?