# How in Scala/Spark create excel file with multiple sheets from multiple DataFrame?

Tags: excel, scala, dataframe, apache-spark, spark-excel

In `Scala/Spark` application I created two different DataFrame. My task is to create one excel file with two sheet for each DataFrame.

I decided to use [spark-excel](https://github.com/crealytics/spark-excel) library but I am little bit confused. As far as I understand the future excel file is saved in the hdfs file system, right? I need to set the path of the future excel file in `.save()` method, right? Also I don't understand what format should be in `dataAddress` option?

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset
import spark.implicits._

val df1 = Seq(
    ("2019-01-01 00:00:00", "7056589658"),
    ("2019-02-02 00:00:00", "7778965896")
).toDF("DATE_TIME", "PHONE_NUMBER")

df1.show()

val df2 = Seq(
    ("2019-01-01 01:00:00", "194.67.45.126"),
    ("2019-02-02 00:00:00", "102.85.62.100"),
    ("2019-03-03 03:00:00", "102.85.62.100")
).toDF("DATE_TIME", "IP")

df2.show()

df1.write
    .format("com.crealytics.spark.excel")
    .option("dataAddress", "'First'!A1:B1000")
    .option("useHeader", "true")
    .mode("append")
    .save("/hdd/home/NNogerbek/data.xlsx")

df2.write
    .format("com.crealytics.spark.excel")
    .option("dataAddress", "'Second'!A1:B1000")
    .option("useHeader", "true")
    .mode("append")
    .save("/hdd/home/NNogerbek/data.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing is this is [maven dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.crealytics/spark-excel_2.11/0.12.0) I used

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.crealytics/spark-excel -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.crealytics</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-excel_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>0.12.0</version>
</dependency>
```

> *Questions : As far as I understand the future excel file is saved in the hdfs file system, right? I need to set the path of the future
>   excel file in .save() method, right? Also I don't understand what
>   format should be in dataAddress option?*

---

what is data addess ?
from docs

> ***[Data Addresses:](https://github.com/crealytics/spark-excel#data-addresses)*** the location of
>   data to read or write can be specified with the dataAddress option.
>   Currently the following address styles are supported:
>
> B3: Start cell of the data. Reading will return all rows below and all
>   columns to the right. Writing will start here and use as many columns
>   and rows as required. B3:F35: Cell range of data. Reading will return
>   only rows and columns in the specified range. Writing will start in
>   the first cell (B3 in this example) and use only the specified columns
>   and rows. If there are more rows or columns in the DataFrame to write,
>   they will be truncated. Make sure this is what you want. 'My
>   Sheet'!B3:F35: Same as above, but with a specific sheet.
>   MyTable[#All]: Table of data. Reading will return all rows and columns
>   in this table. Writing will only write within the current range of the
>   table. No growing of the table will be performed

---

so "My Sheet1'!B3:C35" means you are telling api that... My Sheet1 and B3:C35

### column positions in the excel sheet..

The below is the complete listing through which I achieved desired..

```
package com.examples

import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object ExcelTest {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
    Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.OFF)

    val spark = SparkSession.builder.
      master("local")
      .appName(this.getClass.getName)
      .getOrCreate()
    import spark.implicits._
    val df1 = Seq(
      ("2019-01-01 00:00:00", "7056589658"),
      ("2019-02-02 00:00:00", "7778965896")
    ).toDF("DATE_TIME", "PHONE_NUMBER")

    df1.show()

    val df2 = Seq(
      ("2019-01-01 01:00:00", "194.67.45.126"),
      ("2019-02-02 00:00:00", "102.85.62.100"),
      ("2019-03-03 03:00:00", "102.85.62.100")
    ).toDF("DATE_TIME", "IP")

    df2.show()

    df1.coalesce(1).write
      .format("com.crealytics.spark.excel")
      .option("dataAddress", "'My Sheet1'!B3:C35")
      .option("useHeader", "true")
      .option("dateFormat", "yy-mmm-d")
      .option("timestampFormat", "mm-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss")
      .mode("append")
      .save(".\\src\\main\\resources\\testexcel.xlsx")

    df2.coalesce(1).write
      .format("com.crealytics.spark.excel")
      .option("dataAddress", "'My Sheet2'!B3:C35")
      .option("useHeader", "true")
      .option("dateFormat", "yy-mmm-d")
      .option("timestampFormat", "mm-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss")
      .mode("append")
      .save(".\\src\\main\\resources\\testexcel.xlsx")
  }
}
```

*Note : .coalesce(1) will create a single file not multiple part files...*

Result : since i used local result will be saved in local if its yarn it will be in hdfs. if you want to use cloud storage like s3, its also possible with yarn as master. basically this is based on you requirements...

[image]

**sheet 1 :**

[image: ![enter image description here]

---

**sheet 2 :**

[image]

Also, 
1) see my article [How to do Simple reporting with Excel sheets using Apache Spark Scala ?](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-do-simple-reporting-excel-sheets-using-apache-spark-ghadiyaram/)
2) see my answer [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47827565/647053)
Hope that helps!!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Can I ask you one more question?! Is it necessary to set cells in `dataAddress` option? Let's say I want to set only name of the sheet?! Is it possible? I tried next options: `.option("dataAddress", "'My Sheet1'")` and ``.option("dataAddress", "My Sheet1")`` both of them raise error.

Comment: above program works in local/intellij you can try ur self. AFAIK if you dont mention it will take defaults i guess starting from a0 i guess. lets try it out

Comment: I realized that in `0.12.0` version of the library it is not possible. They're relying on POI to parse `dataAddress` option and afaik it has to contain something that identifies a cell.