# Dataset Spark Read CSV api

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

We are trying to create a dataset which reads folder having both excel, txt and csv files using following:

```
SparkSession.option("header", "true")
                            .option("delimiter", delimiter).option("ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace",true)
                            .option("ignoreLeadingWhitespaces", true)
                            .csv(directoryPath + "\\" + feedFolder + "\\*");
```

CSV api, is reading excel files as well, thus creating garbage data like below. **How can we not read .xlsx file using CSV api of Apache Spark**? Kindly let know

|?�9L�ҙ�sbgٮ                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         |�l!��USh9i�b�r:"y_dl��D���                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      |-N��R"4�2�G�%��Z�4�˝y�7\të��ɂ���

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to construct Dataframe from a Excel (xls,xlsx) file in Scala Spark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44196741/how-to-construct-dataframe-from-a-excel-xls-xlsx-file-in-scala-spark)

Comment: Where are you trying to run this code? Is it on an emr cluster, databricks or locally? And is it on scala or pyspark?

Comment: The obvious answer would appear to be: change the file filter to only include `.csv` i.e. `csv(directoryPath + "\\" + feedFolder + "\\*.csv");`

Comment: We can have both .txt as well .csv, or either of it. If it doesnt find .txt in folder, it will fail, if we add both in csv(paths)

Answer (score 1):

you can use this syntaxe to add different paths at the same time  if you're working with a spark **version < 3.0.0**

```
SparkSession.option("header", "true")
            .option("delimiter", delimiter)
            .option("ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace",true)
            .option("ignoreLeadingWhitespaces", true)
            .csv(directoryPath + "\\" + feedFolder + "\\*.csv", directoryPath + "\\" + feedFolder + "\\*.txt");
```

Comment: Yes, but it will fail if directory doesnt contain .txt,

Comment: you should manage errors and exception by doing try catch.. do a verification process on the files before creating your dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

you can include a *csv* filter ?

```
csv(directoryPath + "\\" + feedFolder + "\\*.csv")
```

You can also try changing the mode to *DROPMALFORMED*

```
.option("mode","DROPMALFORMED")
```

> DROPMALFORMED: ignores the whole corrupted records. This mode is
> unsupported in the CSV built-in functions.

This way if you read corrupted data (ie data from other file format), there are a huge chance that the row is dropped.

Comment: We can have both .txt as well .csv, or either of it. If it doesn't find .txt in folder, it will fail, if we add both in csv(paths)

Comment: why it will fail ? that dosen't make sence. you txt file is csv format aswell ?