# Error opening text file saved with .xls extension in python

Tags: python, excel, text, labview

I'm using labview to create and save data from an experiment. Labview itself creates a text file but saves it automatically with a .xls extension (word 1997-2003--it's an old setup that was never changed because it never broke). Whenever I go to open one of the data files, excel spits out this:

"The file you are trying to open, 'name.ext', is in a different format than specified by the file extension. Verify that the file is not corrupted and is from a trusted source before opening the file. Do you want to open the file now?"

I'm generating a lot of data, so I want to use python to sort it out and do some quick analysis over files in a directory.

The problem is that python doesn't like that it's a text file saved with a .xls extension. It can cycle through the directory just fine to get the file names, but whenver I actually try to open the file or do anything with it, I get the error in the image attached. This happens if I change the extension to .xls, .xlsx, or do nothing with it at all and let it try to open the original filename.

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThrcV.png)

I literally have hundreds of these .xls files. I know I can go through, open each one in excel and save as a real excel file by hand, but that will take hours. Can someone please help me figure a way around this error in python?

[Dropbox Data File set](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/4ny4ppgrjkmt7jb/AABKrNlYjqkRF8g4OnwI19K9a?dl=0)

*Update. Matlab, when trying to read one of the files using xlsread, says this:

Error using xlsread (line 251)
File C:\Users\zane\Documents\Research Projects\PneuFish Project\Data\Nov 28 2016 ATI
Data\ATI_Data_2016Y_11M_28D_16h_36m_01s.xls not in Microsoft Excel Format.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the module `xlrd`.

```
import xlrd
import csv

def csv_from_excel():

   wb = xlrd.open_workbook('your_workbook.xls')
   sh = wb.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
   your_csv_file = open('your_csv_file.csv', 'wb')
   wr = csv.writer(your_csv_file, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

   for rownum in xrange(sh.nrows):
        wr.writerow(sh.row_values(rownum))

   your_csv_file.close()
```

Taken from [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9884551/5724920)

This will convert from `.xls` to `.csv`, which is easily manipulated with Python.

Comment: Doesn't work. In [2]: import convert

`In [3]: convert.csv_from_excel()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError             
----> 1 convert.csv_from_excel()
C:\path\convert.py in csv_from_excel()
     17 def csv_from_excel():
     18
---> 19    wb = xlrd.open_workbook('ATI_Data_2016Y_11M_28D_16h_36m_01s.xls')
     20    sh = wb.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
     21    your_csv_file = open('your_csv_file.csv', 'wb')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ATI_Data_2016Y_11M_28D_16h_36m_01s.xls'`

Answer (score 0):

You've said that the file is a text file, so don't tell Python that it's an Excel file. Just use Python's `open` and read it as text, then do whatever you want with it. `open` doesn't care what extension a file has.

I'm going to guess that the format is actually tab-delimited. From memory, earlier versions of Excel would read in tab-delimited text files with the `.xls` extension without complaint, whereas csv files would always bring up the text import wizard, so this was a common dodge if saving data intended for Excel from a program that didn't support writing real Excel files.

If you want the LabVIEW code to write real Excel files in future, the `Write to Measurement File` express VI has an option to write in xlsx format. I'm not sure which version of LabVIEW first introduced this but it's been there for a few years now.

Comment: What exact Python command gives this error and have you verified that the file/directory actually exists, and is writable if you're trying to write to it?