# Python using pandas to convert xlsx to csv file. How to delete index column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am using the following code to convert .xlsx files into .csv files.

```
import pandas as pd
data_xls = pd.read_excel('excelfile.xlsx', 'Sheet2', index_col=None)
data_xls.to_csv('csvfile.csv', encoding='utf-8')
```

The code is working, however I am getting an index column with the cell numbers which I do not want.  Is there anyway to not include or remove that index column?

***File output***

```
 Unnamed  Data
    0   0.99319613
    1   0.99319613
    2   0.99319613
    3   0.99319613
    4   0.99319613
    5   0.99319613
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [xls to csv converter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884353/xls-to-csv-converter)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

As noted in the docs for [`pandas.DataFrame.to_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html), simply pass `index=False` as a keyword argument, to exclude row names.

```
data_xls.to_csv('csvfile.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

Answer (score 9):

Inspired by miradulo and fix a number conversion problem:

```
import pandas as pd
data_xls = pd.read_excel('excelfile.xlsx', 'Sheet2', dtype=str, index_col=None)
data_xls.to_csv('csvfile.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

Can drop 'Sheet2' if there is one sheet. dtype=str to avoid number conversion.