# Convert xlsx to csv while dropping sheets and keeping date formats

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv, xlsx

I have a `.xlsx` file that I want to convert to `.csv` file. I have done a demo file as shown in the screenshot. In the `.xlsx file`, I have 3 sheets and I want to keep the last sheet only. In addition, I want to preserve my dates in a `MM/DD/YYYY` format.

[image]

Found a few solutions here and there on converting then dropping sheets or vice versa. The closest I have come to is using the solution from this [link :](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884353/xls-to-csv-converter)

But it doesn't keep the date format of `MM/DD/YYYY` and instead converts it to numbers `e.g. 44079`. Tried searching solution to convert the numbers to date but there is nothing on this.

Can anyone help me with this? I can provide more clarification if needed.

I am coding in Python.

Comment: It doesn't look like your dates are in a `MM/DD/YYYY` format to begin with, though.

Comment: Maybe try `xlsx2csv` https://github.com/dilshod/xlsx2csv. Always You can modify and convert using pandas.

Comment: Hi @PaulM.if I go to the date cell it is showing 5/9/2020 as seen in the screenshot. I think the displaying of it is in YYYY/MM. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Hi @ipj seems a bit complicated for me. Need a simpler solution

Comment: Just 2 lines of code: `from xlsx2csv import Xlsx2csv
  Xlsx2csv("myfile.xlsx", outputencoding="utf-8").convert("myfile.csv")`

Comment: @ipj seems to not be working. It is saving an empty csv file for me

Answer (score 0):

Hi I solved my own question by using the answer from this [Python using pandas to convert xlsx to csv file. How to delete index column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42422509/python-using-pandas-to-convert-xlsx-to-csv-file-how-to-delete-index-column)

In addition, because the date is converted into something, not I want in the converted .csv filee.g.

> 05-09-2020 00:00:00

I used pandas and load the converted csv file to a dataframe. From there I used `df['date made'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date made'])` to convert the date from an object to datetime. After that I used `df['date made'] = df['date made'].dt.strftime(%m/%d/%Y)` to get

> 09/05/2020

which is the date format I wanted. I repeat the steps for Date Due as well.

Hope this helps those who are looking to convert .xlsx to .csv and do some formatting on the date.