# How to create a hierarchical csv file?

Tags: python, csv, odoo-9, odoo-10

I have following N number of invoice data in Excel and I want to create CSV of that file so that it can be imported whenever needed...so how can I archive this?

## Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: could not get what do you mean `hierarchical csv` file?

Comment: what about 'save as... -> CSV' ?

Comment: @MrE this is single invoice i have N number of invoice

Comment: same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884353/xls-to-csv-converter

Comment: @Haranadh i have account_invoice, customer,date and under that i have these line of name,product_id,quantity...

Comment: @ADVALAKI, you can also save all the invoices to csv files. so that you can  use the csv files using `csv` lib in python.

Comment: @Haranadh i need all data in one csv

Comment: @ADVALAKI, please see my answer below. That approach would be helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a Folder `"excel"` full of Excel Files within your Project-Directory and you also have another folder `"csv"` where you intend to put your generated CSV Files, you could pretty much easily `batch-convert` all the Excel Files in the `"excel"` Directory into `"csv"` using Pandas.
It will be assumed that you already have `Pandas` installed on your System. Otherwise, you could do that via: `pip install pandas`. The fairly commented Snippet below illustrates the Process:

```
# IMPORT DATAFRAME FROM PANDAS AS WELL AS PANDAS ITSELF
from pandas import DataFrame
import pandas as pd
import os


# OUR GOAL IS:::
# LOOP THROUGH THE FOLDER: excelDir.....
# AT EACH ITERATION IN THE LOOP, CHECK IF THE CURRENT FILE IS AN EXCEL FILE,
# IF IT IS, SIMPLY CONVERT IT TO CSV AND SAVE IT:

for fileName in os.listdir(excelDir):
    #DO WE HAVE AN EXCEL FILE?
    if fileName.endswith(".xls") or fileName.endswith(".xlsx"):
        #IF WE DO; THEN WE DO THE CONVERSION USING PANDAS...
        targetXLFile    = os.path.join(excelDir,    fileName)
        targetCSVFile   = os.path.join(csvDir,      fileName) + ".csv"

        # NOW, WE READ "IN" THE EXCEL FILE
        dFrame          = pd.read_excel(targetXLFile)

        # ONCE WE DONE READING, WE CAN SIMPLY SAVE THE DATA TO CSV
        pd.DataFrame.to_csv(dFrame, path_or_buf=targetCSVFile)
```

Hope this does the Trick for you.....

Cheers and Good-Luck.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting total output into one csv, you could go with following steps.

1. Convert your excel content to csv files or csv-objects.
2. Each object will be tagged with invoice id and save into dictionary.
3. your dictionary data structure could be like {'invoice-id':
   csv-object, 'invoice-id2': csv-object2, ...}
4. write custom function which can reads your csv-object, and gives you
   name,product-id, qty, etc...

Hope this helps.