# Convert .xlsx to .csv - Can't Find Excel Sheet

Tags: excel, python-3.x, csv, xlrd

I am trying to convert .xlsx to .csv. From [xls to csv converter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884353/xls-to-csv-converter/18837202) I am hoping to use this code:

```
import xlrd
import csv
wb = xlrd.open_workbook('Book123.xlsx')
sh = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

your_csv_file = open('your_csv_file.csv', 'w')
wr = csv.writer(your_csv_file, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

for rownum in range(sh.nrows):
    wr.writerow(sh.row_values(rownum))

your_csv_file.close()
```

However, when I am trying to execute `sh = wb.sheet_by_index(0)` I cannot find the sheet.

I also tried `wb.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')` gets error code : `XLRDError: No sheet named <'Sheet1'>`. In short, for some reasons, I cannot find any sheets in the file. Can anyone help me reslove this issue?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Try getting the sheet names with `wb_sheets=wb.sheet_names()` and use the sheet names you are getting from the result for selecting the sheet like `wb.sheet_by_name(wb_sheets[0])`.

Comment: It returns an empty list. But I am sure there is a sheet with data in the excel file.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you,
I found that by saving the file using change the file type to "Excel book (*.xlsx)" I was able to find the sheets. The issue was caused by problem handling with the other type of .xlsx "Strick Open XML Spreadsheet(*.xlsx)".